# Use one controller in custom Block and Page

Tags: blocks, page-controller

I have a custom module with a page and block.

Both will use same API but with different queries and also both will display API data in the same page.

To be more explicit, I have a simple search on my homepage, when searching something, the user will be redirected to page "/search-test" with results.

In that page user has more filters to search.

It is possible to use same controller?

If it's not possible, how can I use 2 different controllers but display data on same page?

At this moment when I search something in homepage, I will be redirected to "/search-test" page but with default result, my page controller is being called and display that data instead of block controller (homepage).

My block twig:

```
<form id="search_data" class="form-item" name="search_data" action="/search-test" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <fieldset>
        <input class="" value="" placeholder="[Name]" type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" maxlength="256" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" form="search_data" class="button">{{ "Search" }}</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My page twig:

```
<form id="search_data" class="form-item" name="search_data" action="/search-test" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="items_per_page" class="form-select">
            <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" form="search_data" class="button">{{ "Search" }}</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am using same  elemnt.

In both controllers I'm using curl to receive data from API.

My block return controller:

```
return [
    '#theme' => 'homepage-search-block',
    '#title' => 'Title',
    "#homepageSearchList" => $searchData
];
```

My page return controller:

```
return [
        '#theme' => 'search-list',
        '#title' => 'Title',
        "#pageList" => $searchData
    ];
```

Everything works good without redirect, when I redirect user to "/search-test" the page controller is called and results will be different.

Comment: I'd probably avoid using `/search` as your path, since this is understood to be Drupal's default search path. And a controller in Drupal is usually a thin controller that simply acts as a bridge between a route and a service. I recommend defining a custom service to handle the actual querying+processing, and your controller's responsibility will solely be to invoke and hand off values to your custom service.